# what's a simple concise way to get the tail of a list iff it exists?

Tags: scala

I'm finding myself often wanting to drop the head of a List, if it's there.  I know I can:

```
myList match {
  case h :: t => t
  case x => Nil
}
```

But that's becoming pretty verbose in my code, since there are a number of places I need to do this.

Anything simpler / shorter / more concise?  I kinda want something like headOption but for tail.... something that isn't going to throw match errors on an empty list.

ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`myList.drop(1)` is equivalent to the code that you wrote.